# One separate object affect another one when u want to edit

Tags: surface-deform

[image]I separated two objects and selected them both in edit mode, but when I want to modify one to move it or something like that, the other one also moves... I don't know what the problem is.In the image you can see when I move the object on z the other one also deforms..

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your *Proportional Editing* option is activated:

[image]

Comment: Omg man! Thanks so much. You save my day:)